# Clickhouse kafka table engine with many consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

I'm planning to do some test with Clickhouse by ingesting my kafka topics into a SummingMergeTree using this method: https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/table_engines/kafka/

For my test on a dev env, I'm not afraid of the volume but on the production environment we are already consuming those topics and we have to put many consumers to be able to read message as fast as they are pushed into. My question is: is there a way on Clickhouse to have many kafka consumer on one table with kafka engine ?

Thanks,

Romaric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the documentation it seems that the `num_consumers` parameter in the `Kafka` engine is exactly what you need:

> num_consumers – The number of consumers per table. Default: 1. Specify
>   more consumers if the throughput of one consumer is insufficient. The
>   total number of consumers should not exceed the number of partitions
>   in the topic, since only one consumer can be assigned per partition.

Comment: Wow indeed, I should had read the documentation better. Thank you